# PerfMon Server Agent responsive for 2 hours only

Tags: jmeter-5.0, perfmon

I am trying to run long SOAK tests (24h) monitoring server CPU/RAM utilization in Jmeter. Using perfmon server agent and plugin. Tests are run headless, using JMeter Docker image. Got everything setup and job is running fine in Jenkins. Measurements are sent to the server every 10 minutes. The tests results are saved in CSV during the test.

However, although the test runs for 24 hours, Perfmon agent seems to be sending data only for around 2 hours. This is how much data i can see is saved in CSV file. Regardless test runs for 5 hours or 24, 2 hours of data is saved.

I wonder what causes it, ideally i would like to see all the data saved for the whole duration of the test. Would appreciate comments. Cheers

Comment: Few things that you may have already considered but want to confirm. 1) Is your JTL/XML/CSV file with aggregate data available for the entire 24 hour duration? 2) Have you seen the CSV manually or when you load it up in the plugin, it shows only a duration of 2 hours? 3) Is the connectivity between the perfmon agent and JMeter persistent even after 2 hours?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Answering your questions: 1) CSV is available once test is completed. 2) I can access it manually (timestamps indicate 2 hours duration, and also opening it in the Jmeter plugin indicates just over 2 hours of data. 3) I believe that the connectivity is not persistent after 2 hours, which could indicate that maybe my client or server has some kind of timeout set somewhere...?

Comment: Yeah. It could be an issue of timeout. Also want to confirm that the agent is alive and running on your destination host even after 2 hours and hasn't crashed. Is it a windows box or a Linux VM that you have deployed the agent into? Are there any logs printed out on the terminal in which you have triggered the agent?

Comment: Its an AWS Linux Server. I am using ubuntu 18.04 OS. I checked the logs, and it indicated: 'packet_write_wait: connection to 3.126.218.168 port 22: broken pipe'. In order to keep ssh session alive i modified: ~/.ssh/config file and set 'Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 240 & ServerAliveCountMax 5000'. And this effectively sort my issue out. Thanks

Comment: Great. Please update as an answer so that it would help others

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by 'packet_write_wait: connection to 3.126.218.168 port 22: broken pipe' error.
This was resolved by keeping ssh session alive, i.e. modifying ~/.ssh/config file and setting required values for 'Host * ServerAliveInterval ServerAliveCountMax'.